# Cant play wav audio file on IPhone or Mac

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, avaudioplayer, audiotoolbox

Im developing an IPhone app and am including a sound file to play. I want to convert it to a CAF file. I know about the afconvert tool, but my problem is any of the MAC audio tools like afplay just return an error:
    Error: AudioFileOpen failed ('dta?')

Here is my command:
   afplay /Users/Thomas/Downloads/cash.wav

I know its not a permissions issue because I did a chmod 777 and can run 
      file /Users/Thomas/Downloads/cash.wav
which returns:
     cash.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, MPEG Layer 3, mono 16000 Hz

FYI, if I open the file in iTunes is plays in there.

Thanks for any help in my problem.
-Tom

Comment: What's with the MP3 portion?  Did someone simply change the extension?  What happens if you change the extension to mp3 and try it?

Comment: I tried to put a mp3 extension on instead of .wav and got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Use iTunes on your dev system to convert this file.

- This file is a WAV-wrapped MP3 bitstream.  While not technically wrong, it's a very unusual format and this is almost certainly why you're getting `dta?`
- This file is at a bizarre sample rate that the hardware decode may not support.

iTunes is quite a bit more liberal about what it will play and convert.